# What's the purpose of .refresh in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I was analyzing the automatically generated makefiles in eclipse and I found a couple of things that I haven't been able to find explanation for.

In the line **"src\Eep.EepIO.o.opt" : .refresh** what is the **.refresh** for?

And what does **@argfile** mean?

Here is the .mk file contents for reference

```
C_FILES += "..\src\Eep\EepIO.c"
OBJ_FILES += "src\Eep\EepIO.o"
"src\Eep\EepIO.o" : "..\src\Eep\EepIO.c" "src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt"
    @echo Compiling ${<F}
    @"${PRODDIR}\bin\cctc" -f "src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt"

"src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt" : .refresh
    @argfile "src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt" -o "src\Eep\EepIO.o" "..\src\Eep\EepIO.c" -Ctc23x --lsl-core=vtc -t -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\Fbl" -Wa-H"sfr/regtc23x.def" -Wa-gAHLs --emit-locals=-equs,-symbols -Wa-Ogs -Wa--error-limit=42 -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\cnf" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\_Common" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\_Template" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\Eep" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\Fbl" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\Flash" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\SecMod" -I"C:\Users\malagonm\Documents\Projects\TC237Fbl\src\WrapNv" --iso=99 --language=-gcc,-volatile,+strings,-kanji --fp-model=3 --switch=auto --align=0 --default-near-size=8 --default-a0-size=0 --default-a1-size=0 -ONrPfceogvIlywakMsU --tradeoff=4 --compact-max-size=200 -g --source -c --dep-file="src\Eep\.EepIO.o.d" -Wc--make-target="src\Eep\EepIO.o"
DEPENDENCY_FILES += "src\Eep\.EepIO.o.d"


GENERATED_FILES += "src\Eep\EepIO.o" "src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt" "src\Eep\.EepIO.o.d" "src\Eep\EepIO.src" "src\Eep\EepIO.lst"
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

`"src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt" : .refresh`

means that the file `src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt` depends on the file `.refresh`. If `.refresh` has changed, it will run the command(s) that follow to rebuild the target, `src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt`. In this case, that command is

`@argfile "src\Eep\.EepIO.o.opt" -o "src\Eep\EepIO.o"...`

The `@` symbol just suppresses the output from the command. So the command that it is actually running is `argfile`.

Comment: Thanks! but what is argfile?

Comment: @m4l490n Does the build work? Because either `argfile` is an eclipse or project tool/binary/script or that's an error in the makefile because a variable was missing or something.

Comment: @EtanReisner the build works perfectly. What I'm trying to do here is to analyze the generated makefiles in order to understand what is going on and eventually make a transition from automatically generated files to my own makefiles. But of all the contents of the makefile this argfile is really obscure and I don't know where does it come from.

Comment: The generated makefiles are likely **wildly** more complicated than anything you'd write by hand (even for the same tasks). So that may not be the best source of inspiration. And like I said, if it isn't an error then `argfile` is a binary/script/tool from either the project being built or from eclipse itself.

Comment: The options specified for the `argfile` command make it look like a c++ compiler to me. `-o <output file>`, `-I<include path>`, etc.